# How to simultaneously execute different function in different page by tkinter by Python?

Tags: python, tkinter

The code:

```
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
import time

def Main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title("test")
    root.geometry('300x200')

    nb = ttk.Notebook(root)

    page1 = ttk.Frame(nb)
    layout1(page1)
    page2 = ttk.Frame(nb)
    layout2(page2)
    page3 = ttk.Frame(nb)
    layout3(page3)

    nb.add(page1, text='page1')
    nb.add(page2, text='page2')
    nb.add(page3, text='page3')

    nb.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)
    root.mainloop()

def layout1(page):
    Button(page, text = 'fun1', command = fun1).place(x=150,y=100)
def fun1():
    for i in range(100):
        print('fun1')
        time.sleep(3)

def layout2(page):
    Button(page, text = 'fun2', command = fun2).place(x=150,y=100)
def fun2():
    for i in range(100):
        print('fun2')
        time.sleep(3)

def layout3(page):
    Button(page, text = 'fun3', command = fun3).place(x=150,y=100)
def fun3():
    for i in range(100):
        print('fun3')
        time.sleep(3)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Main()
```

The output will like this:

[image]

What I want to do is when I click the button in page1 and it starts to run the function, I also want to go to page2 and page3 to run the function in them.

However, if I run the function in page1, I am not able to go to page2 or page3. The program just stucks until fun1 finish its process.

So what should I do?

Comment: You can't call `sleep`, it will cause the entire GUI to freeze.`sleep` is almost certainly not the real code you want, but without knowing what the real code does it's hard to give concrete suggestions.

Comment: I think thread might help me. Can I give 3 pages different threads?

Comment: threads might help, but it really depends on what you want to run. If all you're displaying is a timer of some sort, you don't need threads.

Comment: Ok, different page are different website crawlers. So can threads help me in this case?